# Permissions issue while copying files off a hard drive

Tags: windows, permissions, external-hard-drive

I am trying to transfer files off a hard drive from a old computer into a new one. I have been successful for all the users except one. Even under the administrator account.

I have even tried to open an elevated `cmd` window (right click `cmd`, select "Run as Administrator"), and typed `net user administrator /active:yes`.

I still get "denied".

Comment: It may be denied through a corruption rather than permissions.  Have you tried a chkdsk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CALCS` command. In an elefaved CMD prompt, type `CACLS *filename-or-folder* /e /g:*username* F /s` to grand a username FULL CONTROL of the folder and subfolders

Comment: so what would I type if it was for example in d/documentsandsettings/lynn/mydocuments

Comment: CACLS "D:\Documents and Settings\Lynn\My Documents\*.* /e /g:*username* F /s

Comment: Im typing something wrong, what do I write in the username field. I copied and pasted this and it didnt work.

Comment: Your username that you're logged in to Windows as

Comment: I am logged in as the adminstrator so I typed CACLS "D:\Documents and Settings\Lynn\My Documents*.* /e /g:*Adminstrator* F /s and I get the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: Take out the *'s. I put them in to show that you put something in there